# Flyway Java API Logging

Tags: logging, flyway

I am using the Flyway java API.

I want to see in my logs which sql files are being executed while `Flyway.migrate()` operates.

How do I set flyway logging?

Answer (score 2):

Flyway uses either JUL or Commons Logging (if available). Set the level to debug and you'll see the info.